# Can a single instance of Fiximulator support multiple banzai clients?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

I have been testing Fiximulator and although it is very useful and mostly satisfies my needs it appears that in spite of being based on quickfix initiators and acceptors a single Fiximulator instance can only support a single Banzai client. I have read the available documentation for Fiximulator and can find to mention of it's ability to handle multiple sessions with different compids on differing ports. Does anyone have any experience of running many Banzai clients into a single Fiximulator instance ?? Any pointers very greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

FIXimulator runs on QuickFIX/J and therefore has a [QuickFIX/J configuration file](https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/1.6.4/usage/configuration.html). The one for FIXimulator is located in `./config/FIXimulator.cfg`.

You can add more sessions to the FIXimulator configuration file for each Banzai client that wishes to connect. Give each Banzai client a different CompID and supply them in the FIXimulator configuration file.

Comment: thankyou so much for your answer, I greatly appreciate it !! Although I can connect  to more than one banzai client  to the single Fiximulator instance, when I start the "Automated IOI Sender" the IOIs only arrive at teh Banzai client that was started last. this leads me to believe that the Fiximulator does not in fact support multiple clients(least not in this use case).This seems to be borne out by the fact that if I restart the first Banzai client I then see the IOIs only going to the newly restarted client. Do you perchance know if what I'm attempting is in fact supported by Fiximulator ??

Comment: @steveh I have never connected more than one application to FIXimulator for testing. Have you created a `[SESSION]` in FIXimulator's config file for each Banzai client?

Comment: @TT.Indeed Sir :        [SESSION]
FileLogPath=./logs-syd
TargetCompID=BANZAI-SYD
SenderCompID=FIXIMU-SYD
SocketAcceptPort=9878
ResetOnDisconnect=Y 
ConnectionType=acceptor
FIXimulatorLogToFile=Y
BeginString=FIX.4.2
StartTime=00:00:00
FIXimulatorSendOnBehalfOfSubID=N

[SESSION]
FileLogPath=./logs-fra
TargetCompID=BANZAI-FRA
SenderCompID=FIXIMU-FRA
SocketAcceptPort=9878
ResetOnDisconnect=Y
ConnectionType=acceptor
FIXimulatorLogToFile=Y
BeginString=FIX.4.2
StartTime=00:00:01
FIXimulatorSendOnBehalfOfSubID=N

Comment: I also tried changing the accept port for both sessions. The behaviour is just the same.

Comment: @steveh It could be that FIXimulator wasn't programmed for that, I've never tested that. FIXimulator was just a thesis program IIRC.

Comment: I'm almost certain that's the case. If I manage to get it working however, I'll update this question. Thanks very much for your input, I really appreciate it !!